# How do foreign transaction fees show up on credit card statements?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, foreign-exchange, fees

How do foreign transaction fees show up on credit card statements?

Are they usually itemized out?  Is the purchase price on your statement just 3% higher if you have a 3% foreign transaction fee?

Is it typically done only one way on the statement or does it vary wildly based on credit card company?

I am in the US and my credit card is in US dollars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about the 3%. It is itemized out. They charge you a foreign currency conversion fee which is about 3%.So for example, you are in Europe and purchase something for 100 Euros which is $128.32 in today's rate, your statement should show:-

1.) Whatever you purchased - $128.32

2.) Foreign Currency conversion fee - $3.85 ( 3% of $128.32)

Please note:- I have credit cards with 4  different banks in the United States, and they all do the same thing( I am not sure if each and every bank does it this way).

Cheers

Comment: Did you really mean "is not itemized out?" Because in this case, itemized means that the fees are listed separately, which they are.

Comment: Yes it is itemized out then. Sorry. Will edit

Comment: Note that the fees embedded in the exchange rate (e.g. departure from mid-market rates) are not itemized out.

Answer (score 3):

There was an uproar about this several years ago in the US--that banks were not adequately disclosing foreign transaction fees. They are now listed separately on the credit card statements. I have personally seen it on 4 different credit cards resulting from foreign travel and purchases from foreign merchants (ABEbooks, AmazonUK, etc.). I was also included in the class action suits that were filed against some of the banks about these fees.

Brief mention in article [here](https://www.ricksteves.com/travel-tips/money/card-fees).

Also see [footnote number 3](https://www.bankofamerica.com/deposits/manage/how-to-pay-when-traveling-abroad.go) on this Bank of America page which says in part, "Bank of America will assess an international transaction fee of 3% of the converted U.S. dollar amount.3

3   This fee is assessed as a separate transaction fee on the posting date of the withdrawal...."